# Android SQLite database re-Import

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

in my project i have imported a sqlite database using this..

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
```

It Works fine. But When I delete the database file from the DDMS File Explorer and try to import it again, the code breaks down.

it says no such file found and create a empty database...
Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Please [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) for packaging databases with apps.

Comment: Actually i don't know how to use SQLiteAssetHelper. Can You Give me a Tutorial or something? @CommonsWare

Comment: @AnwarHossain That's what the link is for. Learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Have to delete the previous database before import it again.
use this `Context.deleteDatabase("DB_NAME")`